# Creating a looping if statement in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make my budget more user friendly. 
The part I'm struggling with is calculating the total for each account.

I have my budget set out in columns. 
The final column is the main section (F2:F23) is the name of the account the money needs to go into each week based on the weekly cost (E2:E23). 
To the right I have a list of the four accounts I use in column H7:H10
and the corresponding totals in column I7:I10.

What I'm wanting to do is check for the name of the account in column F and if it matches the account in name then add it to the total for that account.

For example: H7 is "necessities", so I want to check if F2="necessities",
then include the weekly cost (E2) in the total in I7.
But I want to be able to check each cell from F2:F23 and add the weekly cost from column E of all of the ones that match "necessities" to I7
where the total for "necessities" is.

For illustration:

|  |  |  |  | (E) | (F) |  | (H) | (I) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 1 | necessities |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 10 | other |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 20 | other |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 40 | other |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 2 | necessities |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 100 | partridges |  | necessities | 7 |
|  |  |  |  | 200 | partridges |  | other | 70 |
|  |  |  |  | 400 | partridges |  | partridges | 700 |
|  |  |  |  | 4 | necessities |  | quail | 7000 |
|  |  |  |  | 1000 | quail |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 2000 | quail |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 4000 | quail |  |  |  |

Note that I7 = 7 = 1+2+4 = E2+E6+E10; I8, I9 and I10 are computed likewise.

Comment: Another option is to use a pivot table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `SUMIF()`. 
Enter `=SUMIF(F$2:F$23, H7, E$2:E$23)` in cell `I7`
and drag/fill down to `I10`. 
This will give you the sum of all the values in Column `E`
that correspond to an entry in Column `F` that matches `H7` (“necessities”).

[image: illustration]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I couldn't figure out, bless!